# Facebook api, поиск людей

Tags: facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Получаю acces_token так:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=ID&client_secret=SECRET&scope=offline_access,read_stream
```

после чего, делаю запрос:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=jashwant&type=user&access_token=Токен_полученный_с_прошлого_запроса
```

в ответ получаю:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 102,
      "fbtrace_id": "Gd9+EC/P4Y6"
   }
}
```

Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: В ошибке написано, что вам нужен токен пользователя, а не токен приложения. Видимо через токен приложения нельзя выполнять поиск.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что Вы получаете от первого запроса (access_token) не предназначен для таких запросов. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/ Укажите в запросе то что стоит как User token Вашего приложения.
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=jashwant&type=user&access_token={User Token}